# Django clean_FIELDNAME() not called

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

My custom validation method is not working and to make sure that it is even called I added `sys.exit()` to it. The forms completes the saving with the error and ignored the method and it is even not called as the `exit()` has no effect:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms


class Category(MPTTModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def clean_name(self):
        import sys
        sys.exit()
        name = self.cleaned_data["name"]
        if settings.PK_PLACEHOLDER in name:
            raise forms.ValidationError(f"{settings.PK_PLACEHOLDER} "
                                          "is a reserved placeholder!")
        return name
```

Why is that?

Comment: If I recall correctly these cleaning methods are placed in the *form*, not in a model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Worked like a charm, thanks. Please, submit the answer and I will accept it.